# How do I use Polymer with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymer, polymer-1.0

As far as I can tell none of the gems that bring Polymer to Rails is still being maintained.

I'm currently using the [polymer-rails gem](https://github.com/alchaplinsky/polymer-rails) and the [polymer-elements-rails gem](https://github.com/alchaplinsky/polymer-elements-rails), but because of an [unresolved bug](https://github.com/alchaplinsky/polymer-elements-rails/issues/14) I can't use any element that makes use of paper-dropdown-menu. This is super frustrating for me. I can't work out what is causing the bug and no one seems to be in any hurry to fix it - the bug was reported 8 months ago and the're no response from the "maintainers".

All my googling points towards these gems as *the* way to do Polymer on Rails, and there doesn't seem to be any up-to-date instructions.

What is the recommended method to use Polymer with RoR today? Do I need to use a gem, or is there another way to do it?

Comment: I would say that the preferred way is to use vanilla Polymer elements. Or do you have any specific reasons against this?

Comment: Using the vanilla Polymer elements would be a great start. Currently I'm not able to use paper-drop-down-menu.

Comment: Polymer elements are in essence just HTML elements. So you use them as any other HTML element. The only _advanced stuff_ comes with using `dom-bind`, `dom-repeat`, and creating own custom elements. To sum up, think static HTML first, add dynamic server-side content if you see any benefits in it.

Comment: @alesc this doesn't help. I know how to use Polymer elements. I am successfully using them in my project. But some of them don't work because the gem that lets me use polymer in rails is broken. I'm asking if there's any way around this.